# Steps to Obfuscate the spring boot application using Prodgaurd

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war, obfuscation

We have implemented a web application using spring boot. It is working fine as well.

Now I want to Obfuscate the application. I read some blogs and had some knowledge on this and I tried to get this.

I have added the following code in the POM file. It is compiling fine. but when I generate the war file. the war file does not obfuscate(the names of the class files are not changing from the original names).

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>proguard</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>               
        <configuration>
            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
            <includeDependency>false</includeDependency> 
            <injar>${project.artifactId}-v${project.version}.war</injar>
            <outjar>${project.artifactId}-v${project.version}-obf.war</outjar> 
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory> 
            <maxMemory>256m</maxMemory>
            <libs>
                <!--  Java Runtime -->
                <lib>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</lib>
                <lib>${java.home}/../Classes/jce.jar</lib>
            </libs>                 
            <options>
                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
                <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
            </options>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Please help me the way to obfuscate the war 
and how to check whether the generated file is obfuscated or not?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of obfuscating the WAR you should obfuscate the library JAR inside the WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. WAR requires a known class names for declarative configuration to function e.g. filter and servlet definitions in `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you Karol for your quick response, can you please elaborate more to understand clearly.